# How to use my tables in SQL CE in LinqToClasses?

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, database, visual-studio

I'm using SQL CE, but VS shows me this message: "The select object(s) use an unsupported data provider"

So, can't I do this using CE?

Comment: Maybe you use wrong data provider, you shoul use  System.Data.SqlServerCe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to generate your DataContext with sqlmetal.exe instead of with the VS designer for SQL CE.

[Here](http://matthewmanela.com/blog/sql-ce-3-5-with-linq-to-sql/) is a blogpost describing some more details that can be relevant to know.

Comment: I did that, but when I want to instanciate the data context always requiere in constructor a connection.